# Global namespace specifier for function names parsing incorrectly with typedefs?

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer

I'm running into a weird issue with clang that may or may not be a bug.

The following snippet fails to compile on clang 4.2, but does on gcc, because it's parsing "baz::test" as being the return type.

```
typedef int baz;

namespace foo { class bar; }
baz test(foo::bar &);

namespace foo {
    class bar {
    private:
       int f;
       friend baz ::test(bar &);
    };
}
```

`friend int ::test(bar &)` compiles, as does `friend baz (::test)(bar &)`.

I've skimmed over a bit of the standard to try to see if clang's behavior is correct or not, without gaining much insight. Is this a bug in clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard does say that

```
friend baz ::test(bar &);
```

and

```
friend baz::test(bar &);
```

are equivalent.

However, I think it's likely that they should both compile.